# How to remove extra space from bottom in collection view in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I have a collection view,in which i have a cell.On story board height of cell is equal to the height of collection view.But when i run it shows me the bottom space.Please tell me how can i remove that.I have used following code to remove this.

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

    [self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:NO];

    // return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,8,0,8);  // top, left, bottom, right
    if (collectionView==self.album_collection_view)
    {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,10,0,10);

    }// top, left, bottom, right
    else

        return  UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,10,0,10);
}
```

Please tell how to remove it?

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the code where you set up the `UICollectionViewLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that there is only one row of cells. If so you can try to set the cell height in collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:.

```js
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ...
                                                                                                    
    CGRect newFrame = cell.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = CGRectGetHeight(collectionView.frame);
    cell.frame = newFrame;                                                                                               
                                                                                                    
    return cell;
}
```